# Redux and ducks folder structure - nested folders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, directory-structure

I've implemented ducks in my React-Redux project and I followed the guidelines from here: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/scaling-your-redux-app-with-ducks-6115955638be

One of the things I haven't quite figured out is if nested folders is supported by this.  I need this because in my app, I have many modules and each may have many sub-modules.  Example:

```
/paychecks
 /compare
  /select
  /breakdown
 /details
 /summary
```

In this case how would ducks folder structure work?  If I architect the redux store, should I just have one reducer handle all the paychecks related actions or should i break it down into sub-folders like the structure above?

Comment: Please explain in general why you need to break down paycheck into sub-folder. e.g. is there any custom action affecting a subgroup of paycheck only? Also read https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html since I doubt that you haven't normalize your state yet.